# Is it possible to set a default getter on an object when no key is specified?

Tags: javascript

`let obj = {value:'foo'};`

Given object `obj`, I'm curious if it could be adapted so that `console.log(obj)` would output `"foo"`, rather than the default definition/type.

```js
let obj = {
  value: 'foo',
  get() {
    return this.value;
  }
};

console.log( obj );        // want: "foo";  get: "[object Object]" (or the like)
console.log( obj.get() );  // "foo"
```

Note: I realize the answer is most likely "no" for many reasons (like it's a bad idea), but it would certainly make this one task easier (converting a boolean to an object).

Comment: you could probably if you set the object to the window object

Comment: please add an example of the wanted result with call and result.

Comment: But `obj` doesn't equal the string `"foo"` so it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @NinaScholz How do I modify `console.log(obj) would output "foo"` to be clearer as to what I want?

Comment: no, not really ... where should the object know, that a getter has to be used?

Comment: (You can always add a `toString` to object definitions.)

Comment: @DaveNewton exactly, calling an object would return an internal property by default (making it look like a String)

Comment: calling `toString` is dependent of the calling expectation/environment. another possibility is to use `valueOf`.

Comment: @DaveNewton `toString` may be the best option, if you wouldn't mind putting that in an answer, I'll probably upvote it and select it, since the closest I'll probably be able to do is something like `''+obj`

Comment: @DaveNewton my example was bad, but because I'm working with a boolean, the `+obj` would be best and then I can utilize `valueOf` -- again it was your idea to utilize these converters ;)

Comment: @NinaScholz whoops didn't see your comment -- yes I agree, `valueOf` would be better in this case, thought I would still need to modify the source everywhere :(  If you could post that as an answer I'll upvote/select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically two methods returns values, which are not the object itself.

[`Object#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

> Every object has a `toString()` method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from `Object`. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, `toString() returns "[object type]", where *type* is the object type.

[`Object#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

> JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the `valueOf` method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.
>
> By default, the `valueOf` method is inherited by every object descended from [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Every built-in core object overrides this method to return an appropriate value. If an object has no primitive value, `valueOf` returns the object itself.
>
> You can use valueOf within your own code to convert a built-in object into a primitive value. When you create a custom object, you can override `Object.prototype.valueOf()` to call a custom method instead of the default `Object` method.

To break it down for your question, you can implement both methods to a custom function.

When both methods are implemented and return primitive values, the `valueOf` is called first. If `valueOf` returns an object, `toString` method is called.

You might have a look to this article: [Fake operator overloading in JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html)

```js
let obj = {
        value: 'foo',
        get() { return this.value; },
        toString: _ => 'fourty',
        valueOf: _ => 40
    };

console.log(obj + 2);
console.log(obj + 'two');
console.log(obj.toString() + 'two');
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.get() );  // "foo"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```